# SQL Server : fetch next from inside fetch next from

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to iterate each element of a table over each element on another table. In other words, I simply need a loop inside of another loop.
SQL Server has a special syntax for iterating elements of a table, which is in the below(declare cursor, fetch next from).

My question is: can I declare another cursor, fetch next from structure inside of it? If yes - how? If not, what could be the solution?

However I already tried, this and it goes into infinite loop. I think the reason is, inner 'fetch next from' loops don't end because the global `@@FETCH_STATUS` variable remains as zero because of outer 'fetch next from'. Is there a way to distinguish `@@FETCH_STATUS` for each code block ?

```
DECLARE outerCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT * FROM TableA

OPEN initialize 
FETCH NEXT FROM outerCursor INTO @variableOuter

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    --do some operation

    /* Can we declare another cursor, and fetch next from loop here*/

    FETCH NEXT FROM outerCursor INTO @variableOuter;
END;

CLOSE outerCursor 
DEALLOCATE outerCursor
```

Comment: I bet there there's a 99.99% chance you don't need to loop at all, let alone a nested loop. *If not, what could be the solution* - a set-based query.

Comment: Yes you are right. simply, select * from tableA, TableB ; (without join) would solve the problem.